# Do I need both SLF4J binding and adapter for log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

I am confused about the difference between [log4j2-slf4j binding](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/) and [log4j2-slf4j adapter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-to-slf4j/).

Can someone explain in plain English what the differences are? The links I put up say the adapter "routes" to SLF4J and the binding "allows SLF4J to use Log4j", but I don't really understand what this means. Also, do I need both, or just one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use only one. If you put both, you will cause an endless cycle. The following may give you an idea:

- #### Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding

  If you have code in your application like this:

  ```java
  // Instance of SLF4J
  private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = 
          org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
  ```

  And you want to use Log4J 2 (`log4j2.xml`), then you might need:

  [image: Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding]
- #### Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter

  If you have code in your application like this:

  ```java
  // Instance of Log4J 2
  private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = 
          org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);
  ```

  And you want to use SLF4J (e.g. `logback.xml`), then you might need:

  [image: Log4j 2 to SLF4J Adapter]

Comment: Is there a contradiction with the other answer? The other answer says I do not want to use the binding when "your program does not actually use the Log4J backend", except your first diagram suggests to use the binding when using the Log4J backend?

Comment: Hi! Actually, there is a confusion in the other answer. Each statement is with its opposite.